# How to get results from a transaction search for customer that is of type recordref netsuite php

Tags: php, netsuite

I am trying to do some simple stuff in php for netsuite and I just got stuck at this point.

I am running a saved search and getting results back for most of my fields just fine. Whenever I need a field, for example, the customer I get this error when trying to print it.

`Object of class RecordRef could not be converted to string`

So I know I am getting an `object` that is a record ref. I just don't know how to access the info out of it.

Here is the dump for that line:

```
["entity"]  => array(1) { 
    [0]=> object(SearchColumnSelectField)#17 (2) { 
        ["searchValue"]=> object(RecordRef)#18 (4)
```

I would like to get the name and the internal ID of the customer if possible.

How do I accomplish this? I am still new so I know this may be simple. Everything I have tried and looked up has failed.

I can get it other ways, but I need the Internal ID of the customer for later use in my program. Thanks in advance.

```
$customerTest[] = $record->basic->entity[0]->searchValue; <-does not work which is how I am accessing fields that do, For example this works:
$city[]= $record->basic->shipCity[0]->searchValue;
```

Comment: Do I need to do another search on the customer record? If so, I still need the internal id out of the current results to filter the customer wouldn't I?

Comment: I played around a little and found out what I was doing wrong, or really what I failed to finish. If I change it from the above to this:
    $customerTest[] = $record->basic->entity[0]->searchValue->internalId;

that gives me the internal ID at least. I would still like to know how to convert that to the name without doing another search if possible. Which still refers to the same question.

Comment: RecordRef has four fields: `name`, `internalId`, `externalId`, and `RecordType`. You may be lucky enough to find the name in the `name` field. Unfortunately, NetSuite search results very often don't bother filling in the values of RecordRef fields other than the mandatory `internalId`.